# connection and query Google Cloud Platform - PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform

I´m developing my datastore on GCP but I have 2 questions, I´m a beginner and I don´t know about their API. My environment is PHP, and I wrote this instruction:

```
$datastore = new DatastoreClient(['keyFilePath' => 'myKey']);
```

How I know the connection is ready? I was looking for example:

```
if( $datastore->status_code === 200)
```

Where 200 code is ready for example. This question affects the second question. When I try to get some information from the datastore, the Google´s response is veeeery very very very huge if I do `var_dump($datastore)`, and I´m lost, where is my data? The response has information about the hour, geolocalization, browser, etc. This is my code:

```
    $query = $datastore->query();
    $query->kind('foo');
    $result = $datastore->runQuery( $query );
    print_r( $result );
```

Where `foo` as parameter is my kind on the datastore. As I said the response is a very huge object, How can I parse it to JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting any errors when making calls with your DatastoreClient instance, you have successfully authenticated. There is no separate "test connection" method besides making API calls.

The response from `runQuery` isn't directly serializable. Since a query may return a large result set, the result may be split into multiple pages. Google Cloud PHP will handle that for you, but it makes dealing with the response a tiny bit more complex.

If you want to json serialize the response, you could do it using [`iterator_to_array()`](http://php.net/iterator_to_array):

```
$json = json_encode(iterator_to_array($result));
```

You should be kind of careful when using this, as it *could* result in a large number of API calls if your query matches a very large result set.

If you need to do any display or processing of the query results, simply iterate over `$result` using `foreach`:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    // Each `$row` will be an instance of `Google\Cloud\Datastore\EntityInterface`.
    print_r($row);
}
```